# Data Type conversion error in java

Tags: java, type-conversion

**Getting unexpected error**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in) ;
        int number = input.nextInt() ;

        String word = input.nextLine();

        String word1 = Integer.toString(number) ;
        int number1  = Integer.parseInt(word) ;

        if (number1 == Integer.parseInt(word) )
            {
            number1 = number + 10 ;
            System.out.println("Congratualtion its a number"+" "+ number1) ;
        }

            else if  (word1 == Integer.toString(number) )
               {  word1 = 10 + word ;
            System.out.println("Congratualtion its a word"+" "+ word1);
    }
        else
           System.out.println("Something is wrong !!! ") ;

}
}
```

Error message:

```
Error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " "
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at Solution.main(Solution.java:13)
```

Comment: **NumberFormatException: For input string: " "** Did you notice this ? Try to  enter the data correctly

Comment: Why is it unexpected? Did you expect a different error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problematic line: `int number1  = Integer.parseInt(word) ;`

`word` is a non-numeric String; the code is trying to convert it to an Integer, which it cannot do. You might want to print out each thing you get from `input` and make sure you have what you think you have.

Good luck.